# Tensorflow r1.4 Bazel build error : no such package '@sqlite_archive//': Error downloading

Tags: sqlite, tensorflow

When building tensorflow r1.4 from source using bazel the following error is thrown

```
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: no such package '@sqlite_archive//': 
Error downloading [http://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-amalgamation-3200000.zip] to /private/var/tmp/_bazel_<user.name>/b64f453ed39d78b1fe2306a8e1b37137/external/sqlite_archive/sqlite-amalgamation-3200000.zip: 
Connection refused (Connection refused).
```

I have checked the url http://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-amalgamation-3200000.zip. It doesn't work even in browser or using wget. But changing http to https solves the issue on browser. Is there any workaround to this problem to build tensorflow successfully?

OS: macOS HighSierra, bazel version: 0.7.0-homebrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit workspace.bzl at the top of the source directory.

Details: Okay. The problem here is due to that the sqlite file server only allows https connections. A simple remedy is modifying the referenced address to have 's' right after 'http'.

The address references are stored in workspace.bzl which is at the top of the tensorflow source directory. Open it with any text editor you like, then search for "http://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-amalgamation-3200000.zip" and just modify it to be "https://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-amalgamation-3200000.zip" then the issue will be clearly resolved.

Comment: You seem to know what to do here, would you care to expand a little? Edit to achieve what, exactly?